# One account, multiple nodes?

Tags: go-ethereum

In a private ethereum network, can I have 1 account running in multiple nodes? That is, that multiple nodes refer to the same account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But you should be careful when signing, since nonces will not be synchronized immediately.

So there's a small chance that two transactions have the same nonce, eventually one of them will be dropped.

Comment: Thank you, could you elaborate on why nonces will not be synchronized?

Comment: @agomez Between signing a transaction and other nodes receiving it there's a delay caused by the network. So there's a time window where a node hasn't received the newest transaction, if it signs a transaction in that windo it will not use the most recent nonce.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. But you should be careful when signing, since nonces will not be synchronized immediately.

So there's a small chance that two transactions have the same nonce, eventually one of them will be dropped.